# Escape character grammar

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, parser-generator, jison

I want to create a Jison (Bison) grammar for a markup language that allows escaping of markup delimiters.

These would be valid:

```
I like apples
I like [apples, oranges, pears]
I like [apples, oranges, pears] and [peanut butter, jelly]
I like [apples, oranges, pears] \[when they're in season\]
I like emoticons :-\]
```

The examples would be interpreted perhaps as the following (in JSON representation):

```
["I like apples"]
["I like ", ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]]
["I like ", ["apples", "oranges", "pears"], " and ", ["peanut butter", "jelly"]]
["I like ", ["apples", "oranges", "pears"], " [when they're in season]"]
["I like emoticons :-]"]
```

Escaping of `[]\,` is the minimum, but it probably makes sense to allow any printable character be escaped, even if the escaping is unnecessary.

It'd be nice if escaping non-printable characters would be unsupported.  That is, a `\` at the end of a line would be illegal.  That might come free with the regex `.` as it might not include newlines, but it should also happen for other unprintable characters too.

It is difficult to google for this because it's mixed up with a lot of results for escaping literal characters in the Bison definition, etc.

What is the most elegant way to support escape characters in a Bison-defined language?

**EDIT**

Here's what I have so far [and can be tested on Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/try/), but it isn't working (just returns `1` if anything) and I don't expect that the text will arrive unescaped - that would require a second pass.  Is that avoidable?

```
/* description: markup */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

(\\.|[^\\\[])+            return 'TOPTEXT'
(\\.|[^\\\[\]\,])+        return 'TEXT'
\-?[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b   return 'NUMBER'
".."|"-"                  return '..'
"["                       return '['
"]"                       return ']'
","                       return ','
<<EOF>>                   return 'EOF'

/lex

%start markup

%%

markup
    : template EOF
        { return $template; }
    ;

template
    : template TOPTEXT
        { $$ = $template.push($TOPTEXT); }
    | template dynamic
        { $$ = $template.push($dynamic); }
    | /* empty */
        { $$ = []; }
    ;

dynamic
    : '[' phraselist ']'
        { $$ = $phraselist; }
    ;

phraselist
    : phraselist ',' phrase
        { $$ = $phraselist.push($phrase); }
    | /* empty */
        { $$ = []; }
    ;

phrase
    : TEXT
        { $$ = $phrase.push($TEXT); }
    | phrase dynamic
        { $$ = $phrase.push($dynamic); }
    | /* empty */
        { $$ = []; }
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are more than one problem with your code.

The first (and this explains the `1` output) is that `[].push` returns the new length of the list, so what you want is probably push, and *then* define the value:

```
template
: template TOPTEXT
    { $template.push($TOPTEXT); $$ = $template; }
| template dynamic
    { $template.push($dynamic); $$ = $template; }
| /* empty */
    { $$ = []; }
;
```

The other thing is, it seems that you are trying to get too much things to work at the same time, without being really sure that you want them or that they are actually working the way they are supposed to.

Maybe a better strategy would be for you to start small, making it work one rule at the time, starting from the basics.

For example, you could first make sure that you have the lexer working for every case, testing with a simple grammar that just prints out the tokens:

```
%lex
%%

(\\\\|\\\[|\\\]|\\\,|[^,\\\[\]])+   return 'TEXT'
\-?[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b             return 'NUMBER'
".."|"-"                            return 'RANGE'
"["                                 return '['
"]"                                 return ']'
","                                 return ','

/lex

%start lexertest

%%

lexertest:
token lexertest
| /* empty */
;

token:
TEXT    { console.log("Token TEXT: |" + $TEXT +  "|"); }
|
NUMBER  { console.log("Token NUMBER: |" + $NUMBER +  "|"); }
|
'['     { console.log("Token ["); }
|
']'     { console.log("Token ]"); }
|
','     { console.log("Token ,"); }
|
'RANGE' { console.log("Token RANGE: |" + $1 +  "|"); }
;
```

<sub>**Note:** When running in the browser, the `console.log` output will be only in the developer tools. You may find using Jison in the command line with a [script like this (for Bash)](https://github.com/eliasdorneles/shell-utils/blob/master/run-jison.sh) can be easier to test with several inputs.</sub>

Then you refine it, until you are content with it.
After you are content with the lexer, then you start making the grammar to work, again testing one rule at the time. Keep the rules above for whenever you want to debug the output of the lexer, you can just change the `%start` rule.

In the end, you may well discover that you never needed `EOF` in the first place, and that maybe you won't need two different rules for matching the free text, after all.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great catch on push()!  And great advice, thanks.  But what should my expectations be of unescaping those escaped characters?  Can it be done by the lexer or do I need a grammar that processes character by character?  or what?

Comment: @uosɐſ Yeah, I think it's a job for the lexer to deal with escaping. If I understood what you mean by unescaping, that is, removing the backslashes from the token value, you can probably get away with something like `{ yytext = yytext.replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1'); return 'TEXT'; }` -- string replacement applied on the token value.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion and I think I'll go with that.  I also found these links that suggest a way to achieve it without regex .replace.  http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/#lexical-analysis  http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html  http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/How-do-I-expand-backslash_002descape-sequences-in-C_002dstyle-quoted-strings_003f.html

Comment: In your final note, why wouldn't I need or want the EOF?  Can you show an example of a grammar that uses an EOF and an improvement with one that doesn't?  Also, I believe I need two rules because at the top level, commas and closing brackets have no special meaning.  Otherwise I'd have to throw an error.  Usability aside, do you still think I could get away with a single rule?

Comment: @uosɐſ Right, that can be a nice use for lexier states. :) About the two rules thing, the problem is that it could become ambiguous for the lexer, to choose what rule it should use to treat the input. I think you have two options: do it in the parser, creating the right meaning for commas and brackets in each context; or use this mechanism of lexer states that you found out about, starting a separate state when it finds an open bracket and then making the alternative rule for TEXT that only accepts escaped commas internal to that state.

Comment: Oh, I forgot your question about EOF! So, I think EOF is useful in rare instances, only when you really really want the file ending there. Otherwise, just get the parsing working right and it will always complain about a bad input. This will make it easier to change the parser later, to extend it or something. Say you want to embed this little language of yours in HTML, for example, it would be harder to do if your grammar expected an EOF. So, I think EOF in the grammar is just one of those things, "use only if you can't have without it".

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, I did the State thing for the two text patterns.  Works fine so far.  Thanks for everything.